# Strange chapter influence on quotation environment

Tags: sectioning, environments, quoting, grouping

The code below give a strange result when I comment out the `\begingroup` end `\endgroup`: the quotation environment has different vertical space to the text before ("Some text").

What is it that chapter defines that the quotation environment behaves different?

```
\documentclass{book}
\parindent 0pt
\begin{document}

%\begingroup  % <--- remove 
\chapter{abc}
%\endgroup    % <--- remove

Some text

\begin{quotation}
quotation with(out) vertical distance to the previous text
\end{quotation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LaTeX section headings locally redefine `\everypar` to remove indentation in the first paragraph so if you put them in a group things will go wrong.

Also, in particular it causes `\if@nobreak` to be  true rather than false just before the quotation, which makes the latex list code take a different path.

Comment: I see something like `@afterheading`. That makes sense. Inserting `\@afterheading` after my `\endgroup` fixes the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't you just not group your heading, that would be safer;-)

Comment: This is code I inherited from a grand master of TeX with so many complex definitions. I don't dare to change the definition, there must be something behind it. I have now added `\@afterheading` after the `\endgroup` in the hope that it has no bad effect.